# php mysql count column

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to get the count of users on my site associated with a certain company, but something is wrong with my query. I keep getting 'no result' or a result of array:

```
$coresults = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(user_id) FROM ".DB_USERS." WHERE user_company=".$jdata['job_company']."");
$count = mysql_fetch_array($coresults);
```

I have also tried with PDO with no success

```
$nRows = $pdo->query('select count(*) from blah')->fetchColumn(); 
echo $nRows;
```

Comment: If you can, you should [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really not hard](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Have you tried `var_dump($nRows);` / `var_dump($count);` to see what you're actually getting? Have you checked your error logs? Do you have any exception handling? etc etc

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_fetch_array` returns an array of your executed query. Use `mysql_num_rows` instead:

```
$coresults = mysql_query("SELECT user_id FROM ".DB_USERS." WHERE user_company=".$jdata['job_company']."");
$count = mysql_num_rows($coresults);
```

Comment: Will probably error unless `user_company` is an INT, also, that just seems like unnecessary overhead when all they want is a `COUNT`. It doesn't really answer the question imo.

Comment: thanks @Jon for the correction. I thought that user was taking count with help of mysql_fetch_array function

Comment: Thank you but im still getting a result of array. user_company is an INT btw sorry for not making that clear above. i did try mysql_fetch_array as well as mysql_num_rows as well as mysql_result

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by giving a name to your count field and using mysql_fetch_assoc function:

```
$coresults = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(user_id) AS usercount FROM ".DB_USERS." WHERE user_company=".$jdata['job_company']."");
$count = mysql_fetch_assoc($coresults);
```

And then, you access the field like this:

```
print ($count['usercount']);
```

The mysql_fetch_assoc function turns the selected fields into array keys, then you can access them like a simple array.

Comment: I had tried this earlier this no luck I tried your example again and i am returning array as my result.

Comment: And what appears if you execute var_dump($count['usercount'])? It may show the value you want. If it is returning an array, then the result probably will appear in the first cell. Try it and show us what you got.

Comment: I get 3 lines of null for the 3 users i have if they have no value in job_company. when i put a value into one of the account i get a return of array